# Entity Framework validation not picking up IsNullable

Tags: entity-framework, validation

I have an Entity Framework model running against an Oracle Database.

Here is an example property on an object:

```
[EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
[DataMemberAttribute()]
public global::System.String Category1AppliedForString
{
   ....
}
```

I'm validating my changes like so:

```
var validator = ValidationFactory.CreateValidator(entity.GetType());
validator.Validate(entity, validationResults);
```

When the property is null, I would expect to get a validation error, but I'm not. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ValidationFactory knows nothing about the Entity Framework. The Entity Framework knows nothing about the Enterprise Libary's ValidationFactory class. The two frameworks are unrelated.

And that is why they don't cooperate. They don't know anything about each other.

There is no trivial fix to be made.

Comment: Thanks. So is there any way to make use of the EdmScalarPropertyAttributes to apply some validation?